# All the datas are populated into a single row

Tags: python, django, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, django-request

I am a beginner in scraping. I have scraped some data. Here are two problems: All of the data are populated into a single row and every time when I refresh the page, each time the data is saved into the database.

```
import requests
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from .models import Content

toi_r = requests.get("some web site")
toi_soup = BeautifulSoup(toi_r.content, 'html5lib')
toi_headings = toi_soup.findAll("h2", {"class": "entry-title format-icon"})[0:9]
toi_category = toi_soup.findAll("a", {"class": ""})[0:9]
toi_news = []
toi_cat =[]

for th in toi_headings:
    toi_news.append(th.text)

for tr in toi_category:
    toi_cat.append(tr.text)

#saving the files in database
n = Content()
n.title = toi_news
n.category = toi_cat
n.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're indeed only creating one Django object.

You can use `zip()` to pair up each title and category, and then create objects. (I also took the liberty of shortening the for loops into simple list comprehensions.)

```
toi_news = [th.text for th in toi_headings]
toi_cat = [tr.text for tr in toi_category]

for title, category in zip(toi_news, toi_cat):
    n = Content.objects.create(title=title, category=category)
```

As for "every time when I refresh the page, each time the data is saved into the database" - yes, well, the view code is run for every request. You could e.g. check whether a `Content` with the same title exists before creating one to avoid that.

Comment: more elaboration please

Comment: Sure, and you can simply do `if not Content.object.filter(title=title).exists():`.